# Can Java Objects reinstantiate on their own?

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

I have a process in my application that uploads a document to my server via a Servlet and waits for completion, the server then processes the file using 2 threads, and keeps the `Status` while it is running.

This is how the `Status` class looks:

```
class Status implements Serializable {
    private Integer read;
    private Integer validated = 0;
    private Integer processed = 0;
    private Integer failed = 0;

    public Status (int read) {
        this.read = read;
    }

    /*
     *  Getter methods go here.
     *  No Setter methods.
     */

    public void incrementValidated() {
      synchronized(validated) { validated++; }
    }

    public void incrementProcessed() {
      synchronized(processed) { processed++; }
    }

    public void incrementFailed() {
      synchronized(failed) { failed++; }
    }
}
```

Now, the server processes the file in this way:

- A thread validates the read rows according to DB values, putting in a queue those that are OK.
- A thread waits until it has a batch of items in the queue, and then it persists the batch of X items.

The `Status` is updated when the items are OK (`incrementValidated`), when the items are persisted (`incrementProcessed`), and when an item is invalid (`incrementFailed`).
The `Status` stored in a `ConcurrentHashMap<String, Status>`, where the key is the user's sessionID (because this process can handle multiple requests).

While the process is running, the client is polling the server via Servlet too, and all it does is `return statusMap.get(sessionId);` until the process is complete.

My problem comes on files that run for too long, for example 5min. When it is running and polling the server to get the status, sometimes all the values are set back to 0, and the only value that stays the same is the `read` property.
I'm not sure how is that possible, since the object has no setters, so all I can imagine is that the object is being *re-instantiated* using the same value on the constructor, and therefore keeping the same value.

Is that even possible? or am I missing something?
(it looks like the address changes when this happens)

Comment: No, objects cannot be "re-instantiated" in place. Also, you should use the `int` primitive type instead of `Integer` in your `Status` class.

Comment: Have you checked the configuration of your servlet container? Could it be that you have a pool of servlet instead of just one?

Comment: And could you post the code of the servlet, ie the entity that creates and modifies the status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your synchronization is invalid. You create a new object each time you do `++`, hence synchronization occurs on different objects.

Use simple types with dedicated `Object` locks or `AtomicInteger`s.

Besides: are you certain you don't need to synchronize all integer variables with the same lock? In that case you can synchronize on the `Status` itself through marking the method as `synchronized`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm certain they should not be synchronized by the whole object, I don't think I'll use "dedicated Object locks", but I'll try with the answer above, or with AtomicIntegers

Answer (score 4):

Your synchronization is broken. When you do `validated++;` you create a new object (remember that `Integer` is unmutable). So in fact, there is no synchronization at all.

To fix this, make the fields of primitive type `int` (as suggested in a comment) and make the three methods synchronized.

```
int validated;

...

public synchronized void incrementValidated() {
  validated++;
}
```

Comment: K, I'll try this, I don't see however why is the `Status` object's address changing :(

Comment: The `Status` objects address is not changing, it is the `Integer` object that gets allocated on each incrementation. Currently you synchronize on the `Integer` object. If you see that the `Status` object's address changes there is also another cause. See the comment by @autra